# Which of these SQL approaches is optimal?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a fairly large table (several thousand records) and wan't to make sure duplicates can't be created on the same day.

Any SQL gurus out there know which of these approaches is optimal and, if so, could you explain why?

```
{ created at is a DATETIME column }
SELECT `records`.* 
 FROM `records` 
 WHERE DATE(records.created_at) = '2012-02-02';

SELECT `records`.* 
FROM `records` 
WHERE records.created_at BETWEEN '2012-02-02 00:00:00' AND '2012-02-02 23:59:59';
```

Comment: If you were using PostgreSQL, you could use [exclusion constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) to do this directly. (Edit: sorry, got here after you updated).

Comment: Run both and show execution plan to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if compare that approaches, second one is certainly better.
in the first variant DATE(somefield) prevents optimizer to use any index. So in the first variant - mysql will scan the whole table.

BTW: they are not equal queries. First one selects only '02-02-2012', second one  selects 2 and 3 feb.

But. both variants are not appropriate, if you need just avoid of duplicates. Use unique index for that.

Comment: A unique index on a datetime column would prevent two records from being created in the same second.  It wouldn't prevent two records a second apart from being created, since they'd be different datetimes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - the date in the second approach was a typo which I'll correct to prevent further confusion. I wasn't aware the functions prevent the optimiser from using the index - that's very useful knowledge. I have a funny feeling the client is going to change the cutoff for a "day" (4am to 3:59am) for example so I've went with the 2nd option as it future-proofs me agains this eventuality.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like `MySQL`(not my forte) so I might be talking totally nonsense but I would look into

- Creating a calculated column `create_at_date` as `DATE`
- Add a Unique Index on the calculated column.

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE records (
  created_at DATETIME
  , created_at_date AS DATE(created_at)
  , ...
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_RECORDS_CREATED_AT_DATE ON Records (created_at_date)
```

Comment: @bodacious - no problem but I'm curious as to why you prefer a method **not** enforced by your DBMS.

Comment: I've tried to constrain the DB as possible but the client seem to change their minds on a whim so I've allowed for that possibility with validation checks at the application level for now - once they finalise their decisions, I'll try to add more constraints on the DB

Comment: @bodacious - fair enough but take warning that those loose ends tend to get forgotten in the end. +1 on your question and effort.

Answer (score 0):

The second is less likely to trigger a table scan (assuming, of course, that you've indexed `created_at`).

Whenever you do some stuff to a column before you check it (unless the server is smart enough to realize it doesn't have to, which it quite often isn't), that stuff has to be done to each row's value before the test.  Meaning every row in the table needs to be checked.  If you have an index on `created_at`, the server may well ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the table scan - I've indexed created at